# Is HttpServlet.class running as thread safe?

Tags: java

Say, I have a TestServlet class which declared as a global string variable. If there are simultaneous calls to TestServlet class, will this 'message' string variable safe to print without crossing from concurrent threads?

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

  private String message;

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, 
                                                         IOException {

      OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
      message = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
      os.write(message.getBytes());
  }


}
```

Comment: It's shared across multiple threads. Why do you need to make it an instance variable? Why are you not doing `String message = UUID.randomUUID().toString();`, in the method?

Comment: Because the instance variable will be used for other purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A servlet is shared across requests, so no, it is not thread-safe.  A servlet object is scoped to a `<servlet>` declaration in web.xml.

The container creates an instance of the `<servlet-class>` for each servlet and calls its `init` method.

Some references here:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/473015/Servlets/java/Servlet-thread-safe

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnafu.html

Generally, if you are storing state in a servlet, you should consider alternatives.  Why store state there?  What is the state tied to?  Is it tied to the request?  If so, use `request.setAttribute`.  If it is meant to be shared across multiple requests by the same user, use `request.getSession().setAttribute`.  If it should be shared by all requests, then `request.getServletContext().setAttribute`.

If the state is specific to a single request and only within the execution of this servlet, then it should just be a local variable in your method.  For example:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                  HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, 
                                                     IOException {

      OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
      String message = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
      os.write(message.getBytes());
  }
```

Notice there are no non-local variables here.  That is fairly thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

No, servlets are not thread-safe. Servlets should not expose any sort of mutable state in this manner.